# Cannot find option "One account per email address" in the Firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to activate `One account per email address` option. Since I'm using `Email/Password` and `Google` providers.

To avoid Users creating accounts from the same Email address.

I need to add a validation to check if a user is created somehow in either of the Providers in the first place and when trying to create a user with another provider I need to give an error.

To do that I found so many answers by enabling the option `One account per email address`, but I cannot find that option.

I'm Looking at shown screenshot page.

[Providers Page Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7BFm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me the setting shows up at the top of the <kbd>Settings</kbd> page:

[image]

That [Learn more](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/9134820) link was helpful too.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this setting. But I thought this is a different setting

Comment: Same here @LearningStuff. I only figured out it's the one you were looking for after clicking `Learn more`, which is why I included that link in my answer.